# Como atualizar/sincronizar o master do meu repositório no github com o master original

Tags: github

Usando a linha de comando, como posso atualizar/sincronizar o meu master com o master original de onde fiz o `fork`.

Quais as maneiras diferentes e suas opções, qual a melhor, e de que maneira o histórico é afetado/registado.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O que eu costumo fazer é:

Primeiro, faço um fork do projeto original no Github (ex.: https://github.com/gatein/gatein-portal)

Depois, um clone do meu repositório no Github em minha máquina:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:jpkrohling/gatein-portal.git
```

Neste ponto, você tem um remoto chamado "origin". Então, adicione outro, chamado "upstream", que aponte para o original:

```
$ git remote add upstream git@github.com:gatein/gatein-portal.git
```

De tempos em tempos, sincronize:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git fetch upstream
$ git rebase upstream/master
```

Após fazer o rebase acima, meu master *local* fica exatamente igual ao master do upstream, precisando apenas atualizar a versão do github:

```
$ git push origin master
```

Eu tenho o costume de trabalhar apenas em tópicos (ie: a cada nova feature, um novo branch). Quando eu acabo o trabalho, envio este branch para o github:

```
$ git push
```

Então, do próprio github, eu faço um Pull Request dos commits no branch ao master do upstream. Meu master nunca recebe diretamente meus commits, o que facilita na sincronização, já que considero o master como um ponto de início para qualquer nova feature. Quando os commits do meu branch forem aceitos em upstream/master, eles chegam no meu master na próxima sincronização.

Comment: Muito boa a resposta, isso me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 3):

Podes usar o [`Hub`](http://hub.github.com/), Para executar uma *pull request* basta usar o comando:

```
git pull-request [-f] [-m MESSAGE|-F FILE|-i ISSUE|ISSUE-URL] [-bBASE] [-h HEAD]
```

Fonte: [pull-request manpage](http://hub.github.com/hub.1.html):

---

Tambem podes usar o [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/stephencelis/ghi)

```
ghi pull-request [user] [branch]
```

Ou, usando o [GitHub Gem](https://github.com/defunkt/github-gem):

```
gh pull-request [user] [branch]
```