# Replicação repositório Git em máquina local e GitHub

Tags: git, github, versionamento

Existe uma maneira de replicar determinado repositório entre o GitHub e uma máquina local na qual a equipe utiliza?

Em caso de falha dos servidores do GitHub a equipe utiliza o servidor local e logo que os servidores do GitHub voltarem a operar será executadas as ultimas alterações para o GitHub de maneira automatizada e vice-versa.

Outro exemplo, quando o servidor local estiver em manutenção a equipe trabalharia diretamente com o GitHub e quando o mesmo voltasse o mesmo atualizasse os fontes que estão no GitHub. Existe uma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Git tem uma característica descentralizada justamente para poder fazer este tipo de organização.

Você pode estabelecer um fluxo em que todos da equipe usem o servidor local para centralizar as alterações no repositório. Este servidor irá sincronizar com o Github. Isto obviamente pode ser feito nos dois sentidos. Se alguém atualizar direto no Github por alguma razão, o repositório central local poderá receber as atualizações do Github. Tem até como automatizar isto pela API do site e configurações do seu servidor.

Algumas perguntas que podem ajudar:

- [Como atualizar repositório Github depois de ter alterado arquivos localmente no Git?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44713/101)
- [É possível trabalhar com repositório local "comunitário" em Git?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51917/101)
- [Como realizar pull automático com Git?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44760/101)
- [Fluxo de trabalho (workflow) Git usando GitHub?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/65832/101)
- [Como atualizar/sincronizar o master do meu repositório no github com o master original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3389/101)