# Integração servidor de hospedagem com servidor local

Tags: php, servidor, cron, integração

Irei integrar o sistema hospedado no servidor kinghost com um servidor local. A ideia é que quando for atualizado algum conteúdo no servidor de hospedagem atualize o conteúdo do sistema do servidor local, e quando atualizado algum conteúdo no servidor local o mesmo seja atualizado no servidor de hospedagem, sempre comparando se o conteúdo existe ou não para não haver duplicidade. Nós temos a ferramenta cron job, que executa scripts automaticamente. Preciso saber se o cron job com alguma aplicação php possa fazer com que funcione a integração? Se alguém estiver alguma sugestão ou passar algum conteúdo que mostre como fazer um script parecido com essa situação, favor disponibilizar, acho que muita gente tem essa dúvida.

Comment: Existem muitas ferramentas pra isso, já vi alguns usando WorkBench, e o próprio phpMyadmin, algo mais manual seria ter uma tabela no seu banco de dados com logs de alteração e inclusão com data por cada tabela e campo, e criar um sincronismo pra isso

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, acredito que é preciso se atualizar pouco com as tecnologias atuais.

Se vamos tratar de `controle de versão` é obrigatoriamente utilizar tal ferramenta para este propósito.

[O que é controle de versão?](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_controle_de_vers%C3%A3o)

### O que é git?

O Git é um sistema de controle de versão, projetado basicamente para facilitar a vida de quem quer executar projetos em equipe, permitindo que duas ou mais pessoas trabalhem juntas. Mas também é utilizado por quem trabalha sozinho, devido a possibilidade de ‘controlar’ as versões do projeto.

Um sistema de controle de versão faz o papel de “juntar” as partes do projeto, de modo que, cada membro da equipe faça uma parte, e, utilizando este sistema seja possível juntar tudo no final.

É claro que ele é bem mais complexo, mas o conceito inicial é este, cada membro da equipe tem sua pasta do Site, trabalha durante o dia, e no final o Git junta tudo em uma pasta no servidor ‘Principal’, evitando que arquivos sejam sobrescritos e também armazenando históricos e logs individuais de cada membro da equipe.

Outra vantagem do git é a possibilidade de controlar o projeto de forma descentralizada, ou seja, sem a exigência de um servidor ‘Mestre’.

Fonte: http://www.contagia.com.br/blog/git-pra-que-serve/

### Quais ferramentas para controle de versão?

[Github](http://github.com) para projetos públicos ou privados, porém é necessário pagar os planos.

[Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) é para projetos privados com até máximo 5 desenvolvedores no modo gratuito.

### Por que ter controle de versão?

Controle de versão mantém todas suas instâncias atualizadas, seja elas em `branch produção ou desenvolvimento`.

Mantém histórico de todas alterações em seu código, junto com atualizações e regras de permissões de desenvolvedores.

Se tiver mais dúvidas esta [thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88430/replica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-reposit%C3%B3rio-git-em-m%C3%A1quina-local-e-github) pode te ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou analisar o conteúdo que você deixou disponível.